# disable ssh password prompt with -l option

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to execute some commands on a remote machine using the syntax:

```
ssh -l ${USER} ${HOSTNAME} "$SCRIPT"
```

I get prompted for my password on the (local) machine. I need to disable this prompt:

Example:

```
lmasry@elmasry-Latitude-E6430:~/scripts$ ssh -l ${USER} ${HOSTNAME} "$SCRIPT"
elmasry@elmasry-latitude-e6430's password:
```

My authorized key is already on the remote server, so whenever I ssh this machine I don't get prompted for password.
Any idea why I'm getting prompted for password on the local machine?and how to remove it?

Thnx

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/352368/ssh-still-asks-for-password-after-setting-up-key-based-authentication?rq=1

Comment: A little confused. Whenver you SSH, no password. When you SSH, password? Where else are you SSHing from that doesn't require a password? Same box? You using -l?

Answer (score 1):

Add your public key to the .ssh/authorized_keys of the local machine. SSH does not check for any other public keys than the ones in you authorized_keys, it doesn't matter if the key was generated on that machine or if you're a local user.